# Run connected test from terminal with dynamic module (dynamic module is not included in the test)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, testing, instrumented-test

I'm trying to run connected instrumented tests from the terminal, but some tests are failing since the dynamic module is not included in the target apk. When I run these tests from Android Studio then tests are successful.

I'm using the following task

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTask
```

Is there some other task/flag/process that will include also dynamic modules?